# Row number in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, ssas-tabular, daxstudio

I have following DAX code. I need auto increment row number where FileNo and CI_No code are same. I tired with RANKX function but it return rank as 1 for all records. Any one have any idea how we can achieve this using DAX.

Thanks in advance.

Dax code:

```
DEFINE
VAR A = UNION(   ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 201, "Amount" ,200)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 201, "Amount" ,200)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 301, "Amount" ,300))


VAR B=  ADDCOLUMNS(A,
         "RowNo", RANKX(
        FILTER(A,
               [FileNo]=EARLIER([FileNo]) &&  [CI_No]=EARLIER([CI_No]) 
                ),
        [Amount], , DESC
        )        )
 
 EVALUATE B
```

Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with mix of AddIndexColumn (from TransformData) and new Calculated column:

[image]

```
RowNo = 
          RANKX(
        FILTER( ALLEXCEPT('sample','sample'[RowNo]) , [FileNo] = EARLIER('sample'[FileNo]) &&  [CL_No] = EARLIER('sample'[CL_No]) ),
               
                
        [DummySum], , DESC
        )
```

[image]

DummySum = sum('sample'[Index])

EDIT:

```
Table = VAR A = ADDCOLUMNS(UNION(   ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  10, "CI_No", 101, "Amount" ,100)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 201, "Amount" ,200)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 201, "Amount" ,200)
                ,ROW ("FileNo",  20, "CI_No", 301, "Amount" ,300)), "Index", [Amount]+RAND())


VAR B=  ADDCOLUMNS(A,
         "RowNo", RANKX(
        FILTER(A,
               [FileNo]=EARLIER([FileNo]) &&  [CI_No]=EARLIER([CI_No]) 
                ),
        [Index], , DESC
        )        )
 
return B
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @msta42a for your reply. As I have summarize table in variable so I am not able to use M query to create index column. How Can I create Index column using Dax query.

Comment: Then you can use RAND(); check updated answer;

Comment: it worked.  One concern, I have huge table and  Is there any chance Rand() function return same value  for 2 rows . If its  case then Index column have same value for that two rows.

Comment: In my example I add RAND () to the existing Amount column, we check this NewAmount for a specific group of rows and not the entire table (repeating values from RAND should not be a problem, because we do not refer to the entire table but its sections - it is low probability of repetition); If you think that rand () may not be enough then add another RAND or RANDBETWEEN;